# Sort getJson using pure JS - no plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

So I am trying to sort an external json file. The end goal will be to output this data to a table and allow the user to click on the table header and sort the data. I am first just trying to figure out how to sort the data. I am close as the function below works in 2 out of 3 cases. I have to use pure JS and have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=Windows-1252">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="catTable"></div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>


    function sortJsonArrayByProperty(objArray, prop, direction){
        if (arguments.length<2) throw new Error("sortJsonArrayByProp requires 2 arguments");
        var direct = arguments.length>2 ? arguments[2] : 1; //Default to ascending

        if (objArray && objArray.constructor===Array){
            var propPath = (prop.constructor===Array) ? prop : prop.split(".");
            objArray.sort(function(a,b){
                for (var p in propPath){
                    if (a[propPath[p]] && b[propPath[p]]){
                        a = a[propPath[p]];
                        b = b[propPath[p]];
                    }
                }
                // convert numeric strings to integers
                a = a.match(/^\d+$/) ? +a : a;
                b = b.match(/^\d+$/) ? +b : b;
                return ( (a < b) ? -1*direct : ((a > b) ? 1*direct : 0) );
            });
        }
    }


     $.getJSON('cats.json', function(cats) {
        sortJsonArrayByProperty(cats, 'cats.coffeePreference');

        document.write(cats[0].country);
        document.write(cats[0].breed);
        document.write(cats[0].coffeePreference);  
        document.write(cats[1].country);
        document.write(cats[1].breed);
        document.write(cats[1].coffeePreference);
      });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and the following external json file cats.json

```
[{
                    "breed" : "Abyssinian",
                    "country" : "Ethiopia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "espresso",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/Gustav_chocolate.jpg/100px-Gustav_chocolate.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Aegean",
                    "country" : "Greece",
                    "coffeePreference" : "medium roast, cream and sugar",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Aegean_cat.jpg/100px-Aegean_cat.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "American Curl",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/American_curl_2.jpg/100px-American_curl_2.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "American Bobtail",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/American_bobtail_2.jpg/100px-American_bobtail_2.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "American Shorthair",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/American_Shorthair.jpg/100px-American_Shorthair.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "American Wirehair",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/American_Wirehair…JPG/100px-American_Wirehair_-_CFF_cat_show_Heinola_2008-05-04_IMG_8721.JPG"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Arabian Mau",
                    "country" : "Arabian Peninsula",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/3yoArabianMau.jpeg/100px-3yoArabianMau.jpeg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Australian Mist",
                    "country" : "Australia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Irish Coffee",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f0/Australian_Mist.jpg/100px-Australian_Mist.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Asian",
                    "country" : "developed in the United Kingdom (founding stock from Asia)",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Iced Coffee",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/BrownVarientAsianCat.JPG/100px-BrownVarientAsianCat.JPG"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Asian Semi-longhair",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Tiffanie_at_cat_show.jpg/100px-Tiffanie_at_cat_show.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Balinese",
                    "country" : "developed in the United States (founding stock from Thailand)",
                    "coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Oskar.jpg/100px-Oskar.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Bambino",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "picture" : "",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Bengal",
                    "country" : "developed in the United States (founding stock from Asia)",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9f/BengalCat_Stella.jpg/100px-BengalCat_Stella.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Birman",
                    "country" : "Burma",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Birman2.jpg/100px-Birman2.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Bombay",
                    "country" : "developed in the United States (founding stock from Asia)",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/Bombay_cat.jpg/100px-Bombay_cat.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Brazilian Shorthair",
                    "country" : "Brazil",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/Gato_pelo_curto_brasileiro.JPG/100px-Gato_pelo_curto_brasileiro.JPG"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "British Semi-longhair",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "British Shorthair",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Britishblue.jpg/100px-Britishblue.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "British Longhair",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/British_Longhair_-_Black_Silver_Shaded.jpg/100px-British_Longhair_-_Black_Silver_Shaded.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Burmese",
                    "country" : "Burma and Thailand",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Blissandlucky11.jpg/100px-Blissandlucky11.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Burmilla",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/Male_Burmilla_cat.jpeg/100px-Male_Burmilla_cat.jpeg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "California Spangled",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Star_Spangled_Cat.jpg/100px-Star_Spangled_Cat.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Chantilly-Tiffany",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Tiffany3.jpg/100px-Tiffany3.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Chartreux",
                    "country" : "France",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/Abbaye_fev2006_003.jpg/100px-Abbaye_fev2006_003.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Chausie",
                    "country" : "France",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Two Sugars",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/Chausiecatexample.jpg/100px-Chausiecatexample.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Cheetoh",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/6a/Cheetoh_cat_chilling.png/100px-Cheetoh_cat_chilling.png"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Colorpoint Shorthair",
                    "country" : "",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d5/Jake117.jpg/100px-Jake117.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Cornish Rex",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom (England)",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b8/BebopsLilacPrince.JPG/100px-BebopsLilacPrince.JPG"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Cymric or Manx Longhair",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Cymric_-_Norwegia…ric_-_Norwegian_forest_cat_presentation_show_Kotka_2009-02-01_IMG_0687.JPG",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Cyprus",
                    "country" : "Cyprus",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/CyprusShorthair.jpg/100px-CyprusShorthair.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Devon Rex",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom (England)",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Devon_Rex_Izzy.jpg/100px-Devon_Rex_Izzy.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Donskoy or Don Sphynx",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Cat_don_sphinx.JPG/100px-Cat_don_sphinx.JPG",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Dragon Li",
                    "country" : "China",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/Dragon_Li_-_Li_Hua_Mau1.jpg/100px-Dragon_Li_-_Li_Hua_Mau1.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Dwarf cat or Dwelf",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Egyptian Mau",
                    "country" : "Italy",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Egy_mau.jpg/100px-Egy_mau.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "European Shorthair",
                    "country" : "Sweden",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/European_shorthair_procumbent_Quincy.jpg/100px-European_shorthair_procumbent_Quincy.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Exotic Shorthair",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Cream_tabby_exotic_cat.jpg/100px-Cream_tabby_exotic_cat.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "German Rex",
                    "country" : "East Germany",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/German_Rex_Emi.jpg/100px-German_Rex_Emi.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Havana Brown",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Havana_Brown.jpg/100px-Havana_Brown.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Highlander",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom (Scotland)",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Himalayan or Colorpoint Persian",
                    "coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dc/Chocolate_Himlayan.jpg/100px-Chocolate_Himlayan.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Japanese Bobtail",
                    "country" : "Japan",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/JapaneseBobtailBlueEyedMi-ke.JPG/100px-JapaneseBobtailBlueEyedMi-ke.JPG",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Javanese",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/Javanese_cat.jpg/100px-Javanese_cat.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Kurilian Bobtail",
                    "country" : "Western Russia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Khao Manee",
                    "country" : "Thailand",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Khao_Manee_%22ChaWee%22.jpg/100px-Khao_Manee_%22ChaWee%22.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Korat",
                    "country" : "Thailand",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Veda%2Cchat-adult…m%C3%A2le-race-korat.JPG/100px-Veda%2Cchat-adulte-m%C3%A2le-race-korat.JPG"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Korn Ja",
                    "country" : "Thailand",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Kurilian Bobtail or Kuril Islands Bobtail",
                    "country" : "Japan ",
                    "picture" : " https : //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Kurilian_bobtail.JPG/100px-Kurilian_bobtail.JPG",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "LaPerm",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Laperm_LH_red_tabby.jpg/100px-Laperm_LH_red_tabby.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Lykoi",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Two Sugars"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Maine Coon",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/Maine_Coon_female.jpg/100px-Maine_Coon_female.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Manx",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom (Isle of Man)",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Japanese_Bobtail_looking_like_Manx.jpg/100px-Japanese_Bobtail_looking_like_Manx.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Mekong Bobtail",
                    "country" : "Russia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Mekong_bobtail_fe…_Pride_cattery.jpg/100px-Mekong_bobtail_female%2C_Cofein_Pride_cattery.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Minskin",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : ""
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Munchkin",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Longhairedmunchkin.jpg/100px-Longhairedmunchkin.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Nebelung",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Nebelung_Male%2C_…n_Song_de_Chine.JPG/100px-Nebelung_Male%2C_Aleksandr_van_Song_de_Chine.JPG"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Norwegian Forest Cat",
                    "country" : "Norway",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Norskskogkatt_Evita_3.JPG/100px-Norskskogkatt_Evita_3.JPG"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Ocicat",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Ocicat-Charan.jpg/100px-Ocicat-Charan.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Oriental Bicolor",
                    "country" : "",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Oriental_shorthair_20070130_caroline.jpg/100px-Oriental_shorthair_20070130_caroline.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Oriental Shorthair",
                    "country" : "",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Oriental_Shorthai…ile%29.jpg/100px-Oriental_Shorthair_Blue_Eyed_White_cat_%28juvenile%29.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Oriental Longhair",
                    "country" : "",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/OLH-GIP_Divan_Cesar.jpg/100px-OLH-GIP_Divan_Cesar.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Persian (Modern Persian Cat)",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Persialainen.jpg/100px-Persialainen.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Persian (Traditional Persian Cat)",
                    "country" : "Greater Iran",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/SnowyandHazy.jpg/100px-SnowyandHazy.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Peterbald",
                    "country" : "Russia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Tamila_the_lilac_tabby_Peterbald_cat.jpg/100px-Tamila_the_lilac_tabby_Peterbald_cat.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Pixie-bob",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/Jarnac_Bepacific_feb07.jpg/100px-Jarnac_Bepacific_feb07.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Ragamuffin",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/20050922AmarilloRes.jpg/100px-20050922AmarilloRes.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Ragdoll",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Ragdoll_from_Gatil_Ragbelas.jpg/100px-Ragdoll_from_Gatil_Ragbelas.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Russian Blue",
                    "country" : "Russia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Russian_Blue_001.gif/100px-Russian_Blue_001.gif"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Russian White, Black and Tabby",
                    "country" : "Australia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Sam Sawet",
                    "country" : "Thailand",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Savannah",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Savannah_Cat_portrait.jpg/100px-Savannah_Cat_portrait.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Scottish Fold",
                    "country" : "United Kingdom (Scotland)",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Lilac_Scottish_Fold.jpg/100px-Lilac_Scottish_Fold.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Selkirk Rex",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c3/PolloSelkirkRex.jpg/100px-PolloSelkirkRex.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Serengeti",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Serengetimalecat.jpg/100px-Serengetimalecat.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Serrade petit",
                    "country" : "France",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Serrade_petit.jpg/100px-Serrade_petit.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Siamese",
                    "country" : "Thailand",
                    "coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Siam_lilacpoint.jpg/100px-Siam_lilacpoint.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Siberian",
                    "country" : "Russia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Qgcfillimor.jpg/100px-Qgcfillimor.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Singapura",
                    "country" : "Singapore",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Two Sugars",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Raffles_singapura_cat.jpg/100px-Raffles_singapura_cat.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Snowshoe",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Snowshoe_%28cat%29.JPG/100px-Snowshoe_%28cat%29.JPG"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Sokoke",
                    "country" : "Kenya",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Sokoke_dalili.jpg/100px-Sokoke_dalili.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Somali",
                    "country" : "Somalia",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Two Sugars",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c6/Blue_Somali_kitten_age_3_months.jpg/100px-Blue_Somali_kitten_age_3_months.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Sphynx",
                    "country" : "Canada",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Americano",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Sphinx2_July_2006.jpg/100px-Sphinx2_July_2006.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Suphalak",
                    "country" : "Thailand",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/52/Suphalak_Female_in_Tha…umDaengManee.jpg/100px-Suphalak_Female_in_Thailand_named_AumDaengManee.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Thai",
                    "country" : "Thailand",
                    "coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/Mimbi3.JPG/100px-Mimbi3.JPG"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Tonkinese",
                    "country" : "Canada",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Turkish",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Tonkinese.gif/100px-Tonkinese.gif"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Toyger",
                    "country" : "United States",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/Toyger_-_Cornish_…ger_-_Cornish_Rex_presentation_show_Riihim%C3%A4ki_2008-11-16_IMG_0101.JPG",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Turkish Angora",
                    "country" : "Turkey",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Angora.jpg/100px-Angora.jpg"
                }, {
                    "breed" : "Turkish Van",
                    "country" : "developed in the United Kingdom (founding stock from Turkey)",
                    "picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Turkish_Van_Example2.jpg/100px-Turkish_Van_Example2.jpg",
                    "coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
                }
            ]
```

The sort function works properly when called on cats.breed andcats.coffeePreference but I get a blank screen when calling the function on cats.country. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Latest update**

When you sort your recently posted larger json-object your sort function will incurr the following error (visible in your developer console window): `"Exception: TypeError: a.match is not a function"`.

This is caused by your attempt to test for numeric contents. `.match()` is a method of the `String` object, so when `a.country` or `b.country` happens to be empty (=`undefined`) then there *is no* string object where the function `match()` could be found! If you comment out the concerning lines

```
 //  a = a.match(/^\d+$/) ? +a : a;
 //  b = b.match(/^\d+$/) ? +b : b;
```

(or use the sort function I suggested, see my *edited version* below) your problem is gone.

**Update**

I had a closer look at your own sorting routine and found the following:

1. The second argument `prop` is definitely too complicated: You enter a composite object name there `'cats.coffeePreference'` which is then split into its two components. So far so good, but then you loop over the components (in your example `'cats'` and `'coffeePreference'`) and expect to find properties with these names in your `cats`-objects `a` and `b` passed to the sort-callback function. The first property `'cats'` will always be `undefined`, so it's basically a waste of time (and code) looking for it. Luckily you check for existance first, but nonetheless it is superfluous.
2. The check for numerical data is basically OK, but half-hearted. It only looks for strings consisting of numbers and nothing else. So, if a variable contained a string like `' 1'` or `'2.5'` (or stuff like `'-.1'` or `'10.30 '`) would *not* be recognised as being "numeric". A Regexp-based test like

   ```
   /^(?=.*\d)\s*-?\d*\.?\d*\s*?$/.test(a);
   ```

   or alternatively the much simpler function

   ```
   !isNaN(a)
   ```

   will tell you whether `a` is numeric or not.

I tested your sort function and, despite the above mentioned shortcomings: **it still works**!

---

However, here is my somewhat simplified version of your sort:

```js
function catsrt(arr,prop,dir){
 dir=dir||1;                            // default sort direction
 arr.sort(function(a,b){  
   var aa=a[prop]||'0',bb=b[prop]||'0'; // '0' in case of "undefined" entries
   return aa.localeCompare(bb)*dir;     // use string method localeCompare
 });
}
$('button').click(function(){
  var prop=$(this).text(),dir=$('input:checked').length==1?-1:1;
  catsrt(cats,prop,dir);
  $('#out').html($.map(cats,function(cat){return $.map(cat,function(v,k){
    return k+':<span class="'+k+'">'+v+'</span>';}).join(',');}).join('<hr>'));
  $('.'+prop).css('color',dir>0?'green':'red');
});

var cats=[{
"breed" : "Abyssinian",
"country" : "Ethiopia",
"coffeePreference" : "espresso",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9b/Gustav_chocolate.jpg/100px-Gustav_chocolate.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Aegean",
"country" : "Greece",
"coffeePreference" : "medium roast, cream and sugar",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Aegean_cat.jpg/100px-Aegean_cat.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "American Curl",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/American_curl_2.jpg/100px-American_curl_2.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "American Bobtail",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/88/American_bobtail_2.jpg/100px-American_bobtail_2.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "American Shorthair",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/American_Shorthair.jpg/100px-American_Shorthair.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "American Wirehair",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/American_Wirehair…JPG/100px-American_Wirehair_-_CFF_cat_show_Heinola_2008-05-04_IMG_8721.JPG"
}, {
"breed" : "Arabian Mau",
"country" : "Arabian Peninsula",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/3yoArabianMau.jpeg/100px-3yoArabianMau.jpeg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Australian Mist",
"country" : "Australia",
"coffeePreference" : "Irish Coffee",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f0/Australian_Mist.jpg/100px-Australian_Mist.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Asian",
"country" : "developed in the United Kingdom (founding stock from Asia)",
"coffeePreference" : "Iced Coffee",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/BrownVarientAsianCat.JPG/100px-BrownVarientAsianCat.JPG"
}, {
"breed" : "Asian Semi-longhair",
"country" : "United Kingdom",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Tiffanie_at_cat_show.jpg/100px-Tiffanie_at_cat_show.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Balinese",
"country" : "developed in the United States (founding stock from Thailand)",
"coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Oskar.jpg/100px-Oskar.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Bambino",
"country" : "United States",
"picture" : "",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Bengal",
"country" : "developed in the United States (founding stock from Asia)",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9f/BengalCat_Stella.jpg/100px-BengalCat_Stella.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Birman",
"country" : "Burma",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Birman2.jpg/100px-Birman2.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Bombay",
"country" : "developed in the United States (founding stock from Asia)",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/16/Bombay_cat.jpg/100px-Bombay_cat.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Brazilian Shorthair",
"country" : "Brazil",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/87/Gato_pelo_curto_brasileiro.JPG/100px-Gato_pelo_curto_brasileiro.JPG"
}, {
"breed" : "British Semi-longhair",
"country" : "United Kingdom",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano"
}, {
"breed" : "British Shorthair",
"country" : "United Kingdom",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9d/Britishblue.jpg/100px-Britishblue.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "British Longhair",
"country" : "United Kingdom",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/British_Longhair_-_Black_Silver_Shaded.jpg/100px-British_Longhair_-_Black_Silver_Shaded.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Burmese",
"country" : "Burma and Thailand",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Blissandlucky11.jpg/100px-Blissandlucky11.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Burmilla",
"country" : "United Kingdom",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e9/Male_Burmilla_cat.jpeg/100px-Male_Burmilla_cat.jpeg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "California Spangled",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Star_Spangled_Cat.jpg/100px-Star_Spangled_Cat.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Chantilly-Tiffany",
"country" : "United States",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Tiffany3.jpg/100px-Tiffany3.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Chartreux",
"country" : "France",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/Abbaye_fev2006_003.jpg/100px-Abbaye_fev2006_003.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Chausie",
"country" : "France",
"coffeePreference" : "Two Sugars",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/61/Chausiecatexample.jpg/100px-Chausiecatexample.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Cheetoh",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/6a/Cheetoh_cat_chilling.png/100px-Cheetoh_cat_chilling.png"
}, {
"breed" : "Colorpoint Shorthair",
"country" : "",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/d5/Jake117.jpg/100px-Jake117.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Cornish Rex",
"country" : "United Kingdom (England)",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b8/BebopsLilacPrince.JPG/100px-BebopsLilacPrince.JPG"
}, {
"breed" : "Cymric or Manx Longhair",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Cymric_-_Norwegia…ric_-_Norwegian_forest_cat_presentation_show_Kotka_2009-02-01_IMG_0687.JPG",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Cyprus",
"country" : "Cyprus",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/CyprusShorthair.jpg/100px-CyprusShorthair.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Devon Rex",
"country" : "United Kingdom (England)",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Devon_Rex_Izzy.jpg/100px-Devon_Rex_Izzy.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Donskoy or Don Sphynx",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Cat_don_sphinx.JPG/100px-Cat_don_sphinx.JPG",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Dragon Li",
"country" : "China",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/Dragon_Li_-_Li_Hua_Mau1.jpg/100px-Dragon_Li_-_Li_Hua_Mau1.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Dwarf cat or Dwelf",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Egyptian Mau",
"country" : "Italy",
"coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Egy_mau.jpg/100px-Egy_mau.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "European Shorthair",
"country" : "Sweden",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/European_shorthair_procumbent_Quincy.jpg/100px-European_shorthair_procumbent_Quincy.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Exotic Shorthair",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Cream_tabby_exotic_cat.jpg/100px-Cream_tabby_exotic_cat.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "German Rex",
"country" : "East Germany",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/ff/German_Rex_Emi.jpg/100px-German_Rex_Emi.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Havana Brown",
"country" : "United Kingdom",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/Havana_Brown.jpg/100px-Havana_Brown.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Highlander",
"country" : "United Kingdom (Scotland)",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano"
}, {
"breed" : "Himalayan or Colorpoint Persian",
"coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dc/Chocolate_Himlayan.jpg/100px-Chocolate_Himlayan.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Japanese Bobtail",
"country" : "Japan",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/56/JapaneseBobtailBlueEyedMi-ke.JPG/100px-JapaneseBobtailBlueEyedMi-ke.JPG",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Javanese",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/Javanese_cat.jpg/100px-Javanese_cat.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Kurilian Bobtail",
"country" : "Western Russia",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Khao Manee",
"country" : "Thailand",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/98/Khao_Manee_%22ChaWee%22.jpg/100px-Khao_Manee_%22ChaWee%22.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Korat",
"country" : "Thailand",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Veda%2Cchat-adult…m%C3%A2le-race-korat.JPG/100px-Veda%2Cchat-adulte-m%C3%A2le-race-korat.JPG"
}, {
"breed" : "Korn Ja",
"country" : "Thailand",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande"
}, {
"breed" : "Kurilian Bobtail or Kuril Islands Bobtail",
"country" : "Japan ",
"picture" : " https : //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Kurilian_bobtail.JPG/100px-Kurilian_bobtail.JPG",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "LaPerm",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ac/Laperm_LH_red_tabby.jpg/100px-Laperm_LH_red_tabby.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Lykoi",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Two Sugars"
}, {
"breed" : "Maine Coon",
"country" : "United States",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/Maine_Coon_female.jpg/100px-Maine_Coon_female.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Manx",
"country" : "United Kingdom (Isle of Man)",
"coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Japanese_Bobtail_looking_like_Manx.jpg/100px-Japanese_Bobtail_looking_like_Manx.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Mekong Bobtail",
"country" : "Russia",
"coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Mekong_bobtail_fe…_Pride_cattery.jpg/100px-Mekong_bobtail_female%2C_Cofein_Pride_cattery.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Minskin",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : ""
}, {
"breed" : "Munchkin",
"country" : "United States",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Longhairedmunchkin.jpg/100px-Longhairedmunchkin.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Nebelung",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Nebelung_Male%2C_…n_Song_de_Chine.JPG/100px-Nebelung_Male%2C_Aleksandr_van_Song_de_Chine.JPG"
}, {
"breed" : "Norwegian Forest Cat",
"country" : "Norway",
"coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Norskskogkatt_Evita_3.JPG/100px-Norskskogkatt_Evita_3.JPG"
}, {
"breed" : "Ocicat",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Ocicat-Charan.jpg/100px-Ocicat-Charan.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Oriental Bicolor",
"country" : "",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Oriental_shorthair_20070130_caroline.jpg/100px-Oriental_shorthair_20070130_caroline.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Oriental Shorthair",
"country" : "",
"coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Oriental_Shorthai…ile%29.jpg/100px-Oriental_Shorthair_Blue_Eyed_White_cat_%28juvenile%29.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Oriental Longhair",
"country" : "",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/65/OLH-GIP_Divan_Cesar.jpg/100px-OLH-GIP_Divan_Cesar.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Persian (Modern Persian Cat)",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Persialainen.jpg/100px-Persialainen.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Persian (Traditional Persian Cat)",
"country" : "Greater Iran",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/SnowyandHazy.jpg/100px-SnowyandHazy.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Peterbald",
"country" : "Russia",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/Tamila_the_lilac_tabby_Peterbald_cat.jpg/100px-Tamila_the_lilac_tabby_Peterbald_cat.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Pixie-bob",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8c/Jarnac_Bepacific_feb07.jpg/100px-Jarnac_Bepacific_feb07.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Ragamuffin",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/20050922AmarilloRes.jpg/100px-20050922AmarilloRes.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Ragdoll",
"country" : "United States",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Ragdoll_from_Gatil_Ragbelas.jpg/100px-Ragdoll_from_Gatil_Ragbelas.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Russian Blue",
"country" : "Russia",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Russian_Blue_001.gif/100px-Russian_Blue_001.gif"
}, {
"breed" : "Russian White, Black and Tabby",
"country" : "Australia",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Sam Sawet",
"country" : "Thailand",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande"
}, {
"breed" : "Savannah",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/Savannah_Cat_portrait.jpg/100px-Savannah_Cat_portrait.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Scottish Fold",
"country" : "United Kingdom (Scotland)",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Lilac_Scottish_Fold.jpg/100px-Lilac_Scottish_Fold.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Selkirk Rex",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/c/c3/PolloSelkirkRex.jpg/100px-PolloSelkirkRex.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Serengeti",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "Cream, No Sugar",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1a/Serengetimalecat.jpg/100px-Serengetimalecat.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Serrade petit",
"country" : "France",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c7/Serrade_petit.jpg/100px-Serrade_petit.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Siamese",
"country" : "Thailand",
"coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/25/Siam_lilacpoint.jpg/100px-Siam_lilacpoint.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Siberian",
"country" : "Russia",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1c/Qgcfillimor.jpg/100px-Qgcfillimor.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Singapura",
"country" : "Singapore",
"coffeePreference" : "Two Sugars",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Raffles_singapura_cat.jpg/100px-Raffles_singapura_cat.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Snowshoe",
"country" : "United States",
"coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4b/Snowshoe_%28cat%29.JPG/100px-Snowshoe_%28cat%29.JPG"
}, {
"breed" : "Sokoke",
"country" : "Kenya",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/94/Sokoke_dalili.jpg/100px-Sokoke_dalili.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Somali",
"country" : "Somalia",
"coffeePreference" : "Two Sugars",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c6/Blue_Somali_kitten_age_3_months.jpg/100px-Blue_Somali_kitten_age_3_months.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Sphynx",
"country" : "Canada",
"coffeePreference" : "Americano",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/Sphinx2_July_2006.jpg/100px-Sphinx2_July_2006.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Suphalak",
"country" : "Thailand",
"coffeePreference" : "Carmel Latte Grande",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/5/52/Suphalak_Female_in_Tha…umDaengManee.jpg/100px-Suphalak_Female_in_Thailand_named_AumDaengManee.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Thai",
"country" : "Thailand",
"coffeePreference" : "French Roast",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/57/Mimbi3.JPG/100px-Mimbi3.JPG"
}, {
"breed" : "Tonkinese",
"country" : "Canada",
"coffeePreference" : "Turkish",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Tonkinese.gif/100px-Tonkinese.gif"
}, {
"breed" : "Toyger",
"country" : "United States",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/Toyger_-_Cornish_…ger_-_Cornish_Rex_presentation_show_Riihim%C3%A4ki_2008-11-16_IMG_0101.JPG",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}, {
"breed" : "Turkish Angora",
"country" : "Turkey",
"coffeePreference" : "Skinny Mocha Latte",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Angora.jpg/100px-Angora.jpg"
}, {
"breed" : "Turkish Van",
"country" : "developed in the United Kingdom (founding stock from Turkey)",
"picture" : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Turkish_Van_Example2.jpg/100px-Turkish_Van_Example2.jpg",
"coffeePreference" : "Cafe Au Lait"
}];
```

```css
span {font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">descending<br>
<button>breed</button><button>country</button><button>coffeePreference</button>
<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is the json file is external and I have to use a getJson call to retrieve the data.

Comment: Well, from your post I gathered you had no problems receiving the data through `getJSON()` so I started from the point where the actual array needed to be sorted. So, getting the data then **is** still a problem?

Comment: This is very close, but I am still having the same problem. I can not sort on country when I use my cats. json data. It works above with the smaller cats variable, but not with the entire file.

Comment: Can you publish your (possibly shortened, but still containing the critical data) json file? There might be a value in there that upsets the sorting routine.